# Como desabilitar um select associaition do simple form

Tags: ruby, rails4

Tenho um select association do simple form, o valor dele repasso via controler e gostaria que no form o usuário não tivesse a opção de selecionar outro valor. Já tentei usar disabled:true (Desabilita como quero mas não envia o valor quando salva) disabled: [true], input_html: {disabled: true} e readonly: true sendo que nenhuma dessas resolveu o problema, sempre permitindo selecionar outro valor no select. Alguma sugestão de como mostrar o valor selecionado sem que o usuário possa selecionar outro?

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode trocar o campo select por um campo tipo texto simples quando estiver na tela de edição ou não colocar campo algum mantendo apenas o texto em uma div.

Uma outra opção é manter como esta e criar uma regra no model `before_update` não permitindo que o valor inicialmente cadastrado não seja alterado.